# netconf call home using ipv6

Tags: python, ipv6, netconf

Can some one please help me in implementing netconf call home using ipv6 in python. Just read some articles about netconf home and tried implementing the same with below code , Can someone please check and tell me if I am heading in the right direction or what's need to be done so that I will receive the signal on my ipv6 when my network device send it.

```
from netconf_client.connect import connect_tls, CallhomeManager
from netconf_client.ncclient import Manager


with CallhomeManager(port=4335) as call_home_mgr:
    try :
        session = call_home_mgr.accept_one_tls(host='::',port=4335, keyfile='key.pem',
                                           certfile='cert.pem',
                                           ca_certs='cacert.pem', timeout=6000)

        print('session:', session)
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)

with Manager(session) as mgr:
    print('get_config', mgr.get_config(source='running'))
```

Comment: How can you receive a signal on an ipv6?  Ip (of any version) is a protocol, not a thing

Comment: This q needs a clear statement of what you're actually trying to do

Comment: Hi @2e0byo : Sorry for not asking the clear question here . The ask is to implement the netconf call home using python and when i wireshark the network traffic  all the network devices are using IPV6 and not IPV4 , Can you please guide me how to do it . Any example or link will be appreciated.

Comment: Again I don't understand.  This code is copied from the `netconf_client` docs.  Have you tried running it?  What problem do you have with it?  netconf *client* is, as the name suggests, a client: the `CallhomeManager` *accepts* callhome requests, it doesn't send them. If you want to send them, you need a netconf *server*, of which [there are several](https://netconf.readthedocs.io/en/master/).  Again, what are you trying to do?  Netconf is used for a few generally advanced networking setups.  Are you just playing, or are you trying to do something else, like send a message over a network?

Comment: As a general rule 'will my code work' questions are off topic here.  The only way to answer that question is to run it against a thorough test suite.